# How to add MongoDB sampler in Jmeter 5.1.1?

Tags: mongodb, jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0

I am trying to create a jMeter script which need to connect to a MongoDB.
I need to read the documents and add assertions and this is not for a performance test.

Which sampler do I use to connect MongoDB?
Do I need to place any external jars to bin folder?
Also, I am using Jmeter 5.1.1. I don't see the Plugins Manager in the options menu.

Answer (score 1):

JMeter's [Mongo support is deprecated](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#MongoDB_Script_(DEPRECATED)) , use scripting in JSR223 component instead

> it is better to avoid using this element for load testing and use JSR223+Groovy scripting using MongoDBHolder instead

Plugins Manager isn't included in JMeter core (yet), you need to [download it](https://jmeter-plugins.org/install/Install/)

> Download plugins-manager.jar and put it into lib/ext directory, then restart JMeter.

Answer (score 1):

1. Add the next line to *user.properties* file:

   ```
   not_in_menu=
   ```
2. Restart JMeter to pick up the change
3. That's it, you should now see MongoDB test elements

Be aware that starting from [MongoDB 3](https://www.mongodb.com/mongodb-3.6) there is a [new approach with regards to MongoDB asynchronous queries](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/jmeter-dev/201512.mbox/%3CCAH9fUpZNm%3DcWo5Pv-XQfWuNkxgLp7UwmMDZVVRFRF7jEogMUWw%40mail.gmail.com%3E) architecture which is not very compatible with JMeter threads model therefore you might want to add the latest version of the MongoDB client libraries and write your tests in Groovy, check out [MongoDB Performance Testing with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/mongodb-performance-testing-with-jmeter/) article for more details.